# Why is s_addr within in_addr an unsigned long instead of a mere unsigned if ip's are 4 octets?

Tags: c, networking

Is it for ipv6? If ipv4 is s_addr just the dotted quad reinterpreted as a 32 bit integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unsgined long` guarantees that the size of the variable is at least 4 bytes, thus holding the entire ip. An unsigned int can be smaller.

Comment: +1 True.  `unsigned` C specified _minimum_ range is 0 to 65535 and `unsigned long` is 0 to `power(2,32)-1`.